# Solve the following differential equation using Laplace transforms

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Could you help to answer following question I am stuck on it..

Solve the following differential equation using Laplace transforms
$$dx/dt-3x=-13\sin(2t)$$

At $t=0, x=2$

Comment: gone as far as Sf(S) - 3f(s) = -26/S^2+2 +2   stuck after this

Comment: Well, now you can solve for $f(s),$ and take the inverse laplace transform, no?

Comment: unsure how to do that.. new to this

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

- $\mathscr{L}(x'(t)) = s x(s) -x(0) = s x(s) - 2$
- $\mathscr{L}(-3 x(t)) = -3x(s)$
- $\mathscr{L}(-13\sin(2t)) = -\dfrac{26}{s^2+4}$

Can you now continue?

You want to solve for $x(s)$ on the LHS, do a partial fraction expansion and then find the Inverse Laplace transform.

**Spoiler**

> $x(t) = 2 \cos(2 t) + 3 \sin(2 t)$

Comment: Thanks .... :-) Time for the showers and the gym!